# What is the push forward of the canonical class?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be an abelian surface over $\mathbb{C}$. And let $i:X\longrightarrow X$ be the inverse map. $i$ is a degree 2 morphism. We consider $Y$ the quotient of $X$ by the action of $i$, that is, $Y=X/\langle i\rangle$. Now this is a singular surface whose singularities are 16 nodes. $\tilde{Y}$, the desingularization of $Y$ is a K3 surface.

My question is as follows. We have two canonical maps. $\pi: X\longrightarrow Y$ and the blow up map $f:\tilde{Y}\longrightarrow Y$. What is the push forward of the canonical line bundle $K$ of $X$ under $\pi$. I am guessing that it is trivial since $ K $ is trivial (since $X$ is an abelian surface) and the canonical bundle of $\tilde{Y}$ (which is isomorphic to $Y$ outside the exceptional locus) is trivial. Is this right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $K=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\pi$ is of degree 2, the push forward is a rank two torsion free sheaf of the form $\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus F$. Since $Y$ is singular, it is easy to see that $F$ is not locally free and thus the push forward is not trivial.

Comment: @Mohan's comment highlights an important thing to keep in mind here: there is no such thing as _pushforward of line bundles_. Instead there are two possible things you could do: push forward an invertible sheaf, or push forward a divisor in the canonical class. These give completely different results.

Comment: @Mohan, Why have you said that the push forward is a rank 2 torsion free sheaf? How do we get this?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a finite surjective map of varieties of degree $n$ and $V$ is a rank $r$ sheaf on $X$, $f_*V$ is a rank $rn$ sheaf on $Y$.

Comment: @Mohan, can you tell me why the push forward is not locally free. I am just not able to figure out, sorry!

Comment: Try to calculate this for $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to C$ where $f$ is birational, but $C$ is not smooth.